# Access a stand-alone php file with WordPress installed

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm wanting to upload a standard php file to the root of my website which also has WordPress installed. I think there is something with the .htaccess file that's not letting me access a file even if it exists but instead passing every call through to WordPress's index.php file which in turn throws me to a WordPress 'page can't be found'.

I've looked through similar questions on here with no avail.

What I'm thinking is there is something funky going on, or I need to modify my .htaccess from the standard one that ships with WordPress or ??

Any help is appreciated!!

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Comment: can you post the contents of your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your file is called `foo.php`, add this line to your `.htaccess` file, directly below `RewriteEngine on`:

```
RewriteRule ^foo.php$ - [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `RewriteCond` with the name of the file you want to access, that checks if the current file is the file that you want to access.